# Is there a way to suppress referential integrity for specific records?

Tags: ms-access, referential-integrity

I have a table of ***people*** and another ***deliverers*** holding details of how deliveries are made. Most deliveries are made by someone in the people table so there is a ***peopleId*** which points to the ***people*** table. However, some are generic e.g. post, collect, etc. i.e. there is no peopleId. Is there a way of e.g. leaving peopleId blank or null which would not cause a referential integrity problem. The only other way I can think of is to add dummy records to the people table.

Comment: Is the foreign key field for peopleId set as "Required" in table? Don't require input and can have Null and still enforce referential integrity. RI just won't allow an input that does not have match in people.

Comment: No. Either RI is implemented or it is not.